# Value change my link without updating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new and my English is very mean.
I'm looking for a way to change the value of my link by clicking on one of the checkbox.
Let 1 = series
Soite 2 = movie
How can I do?
Current code running reloading the page.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['g'])){$g = $_POST['g'];?>
<form id="tform" method="post">
    <input  type="checkbox" id="1" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "serie") {echo  'checked="checked"';} ?> value="serie" class="checkbox">
    <label for="1">Série</label>
    <input  type="checkbox" id="2" name="g"<?php if ($_POST['g'] == "film") {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="film" class="checkbox">
    <label for="2">Film</label>
</form>
```

In this link:

```
   function grab(code) {
            $.ajax({
            url: '/movies.php?g=?g=<?= $g; ?>&code='+code+'',
            async: true, 
            beforeSend: function() {
            $('#infos').html('<br /><br /><div class="load" id="load"><center>Chargement des données<br /><img src="/images/loader.gif" alt="Chargement des données en cours..." /></center></div><br /><br />');
            $('#infos').show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#infos').empty();
                $('#infos').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('input[name=g]').change(function(){
    $('#tform').submit();

   });
});
```

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Where is that link in your PHP? If it's in Javascript, please add that code to your question.

Comment: Sorry i'm new member :/ thank to hemp me please.

Comment: do you speak portuguese?

Comment: change the method to get and use $_GET instead $_POST. is that it?

Comment: @csbenjamin, sorry but no ? Why this question ? lol

Comment: never mind, it was because I spaeak and I saw portuguese in you code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `data:` option to `$.ajax`.

```
function grab(code) {
    var gval = $("#tform :checkbox:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/movies.php',
        method: "GET",
        data: { 'g': gval, code: code },
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#infos').html('<br /><br /><div class="load" id="load"><center>Chargement des données<br /><img src="/images/loader.gif" alt="Chargement des données en cours..." /></center></div><br /><br />').show();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#infos').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, i cant' change this because i have a error in this here:  $.ajax({

Comment: I left out a comma on the `data` line, fixed it.

Comment: Just made another change. I mistakenly thought you were using array-style parameters for `g`, but that was in someone's answer, not your question. I changed the answer to use a single value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['g'])){$g = $_POST['g'];?>
<form id="tform" method="post">
    <input  type="checkbox" id="1" name="g[]"<?php if (in_array("serie",$g)) {echo  'checked="checked"';} ?> value="serie" class="checkbox">
    <label for="1">Série</label>
    <input  type="checkbox" id="2" name="g[]"<?php if (in_array("film",$g)) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="film" class="checkbox">
    <label for="2">Film</label>
</form>
```

Comment: you can not change the $g variable on client side. To change something on client side you need use javascript

Comment: It is impossible with out not posting any data, if you want do this, you can use javascript. but javascript can not change the value of $g php .